# How to retrieve value from a nested JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a following JSON.

Data:

```
{
posts: [{
    thread: {
        uuid: "8d4d59ad10e0b5df2a9f3cac30f1a6b96e809233",
        url: "http://www.esquire.com/entertainment/news/a53604/deadpool-2-teaser/",
        site_full: "www.esquire.com",
        site: "esquire.com",
        site_section: "",
        site_categories: [
            "news",
            "entertainment",
            "education"
        ],
        section_title: "",
        title: "The Deadpool 2 Teaser Just Dropped and It's Great",
        title_full: "The Deadpool 2 Teaser Just Dropped and It's Great",
        published: "2017-03-05T00:45:28.810+02:00",
        replies_count: 0,
        participants_count: 0,
        site_type: "news",
        country: "US",
        spam_score: 0.127,
        main_image: "http://esq.h-cdn.co/assets/17/09/1600x800/landscape-1488661852-            deadpool2-630x400-copy.jpg",
        performance_score: 9,
        domain_rank: 1790,
        social: {
            facebook: {
                likes: 999,
                comments: 0,
                shares: 999
            },
            gplus: {
                shares: 0
            },
            pinterest: {
                shares: 0
            },
            linkedin: {
                shares: 0
            },
            stumbledupon: {
                shares: 0
            },
            vk: {
                shares: 0
            }
        }
    },
    uuid: "XXXXX",
    url: "http://www.esquire.com/entertainment/news/a53604/deadpool-2-teaser/",
    ord_in_thread: 0,
    author: "Peter Wade",
    published: "2017-03-05T00:45:28.810+02:00",
    title: "The Deadpool 2 Teaser Just Dropped and It's Great",
    text: "The Deadpool 2 Teaser Just Dropped and It's Great "
    Anyone know the number to 911 ? " Most Popular By Peter Wade Mar 4, 2017 The Deadpool 2 teaser trailer that has been playing exclusively in theaters before Logan was officially released by Ryan Reynolds on Saturday. As expected, Deadpool is still a second-rate hero and a fan of butt jokes, struggling to even get his super hero suit on Superman-style in a phone booth while a senior citizen is being mugged nearby. Related Story Ryan Reynolds Was Kind to Drugged-Up Deadpool Fan Advertisement - Continue Reading Below "
    Somebody save me!Is there anybody in this world who can help me,
    for God 's sake?" the man screams helplessly while Reynolds'
    Deadpool smashes his ass against the booth 's glass. GIF Most Popular Then Stan Lee appeared, and things went downhill from there. If you look closely, another clue lurks in the form of graffiti on the side of the phone booth that reads, "Nathan Summers, Cumming Soon!" The name is a reference to X-Men character Cable, a.k.a. Nathan Summers, hinting that he may be Deadpool'
    s foe this time around.Deadpool 2 is a little less than a year away,
    with a scheduled release date of March 2,
    2018. Related Story ",
    highlightText : "",
    highlightTitle: "",
    language: "english",
    external_links: [],
    entities: {
        persons: [{
                name: "reynolds",
                sentiment: "none"
            },
            {
                name: "deadpool",
                sentiment: "none"
            },
            {
                name: "peter wade mar",
                sentiment: "none"
            },
            {
                name: "ryan reynolds",
                sentiment: "none"
            },
            {
                name: "stan lee",
                sentiment: "none"
            },
            {
                name: "nathan summers",
                sentiment: "none"
            }
        ],
        organizations: [{
            name: "deadpool",
            sentiment: "positive"
        }],
        locations: [{
            name: "logan",
            sentiment: "none"
        }]
    },
    rating: null,
    crawled: "2017-03-05T00:45:28.810+02:00"
}],
totalResults: 3411,
moreResultsAvailable: 3410,
next: "/filterWebContent?token=XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-    XXXXX&format=json&ts=1488464225907&q=deadpool&sort=social.facebook.likes&from=1&    sort=desc&size=1",
requestsLeft: 999911
}
```

The problem:

I am trying to extract some of the fields from this JSON. However some fields are highly nested, some are single nested.

For example, using the "posts" field I can get value for title, author, language keys. However, using the following code when I am trying to get the value for country, locations, persons, organisations, sentiment, I am getting null for all of them. My code snippet is as follows.

```
JsonArray postArray = result.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("posts");
System.out.println(postArray);
for(JsonElement o  : postArray) {
    System.out.println(o.getAsJsonObject().get("title"));  
    System.out.println(o.getAsJsonObject().get("author")); 
    System.out.println(o.getAsJsonObject().get("language"));   
    System.out.println(o.getAsJsonObject().get("country"));  
    System.out.println(o.getAsJsonObject().get("locations"));   
    System.out.println(o.getAsJsonObject().get("persons"));
    System.out.println(o.getAsJsonObject().get("organizations"));
    System.out.println(o.getAsJsonObject().get("sentiment"));
    System.out.println ("--------------------------------------");
}
```

How do I print values corresponding to the all the fields/keys ?

Comment: where is your json?

Comment: instead of calling `o.getAsJsonObject()` multiple times, just call it once at the beginning of the loop and store it in a variable

Comment: your json is malformed

Comment: Can't do much about the Json. This is what i get from some other source.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of recursion on your java object.

- Check your value Is a JSON Object. If yes make recursion call
- Else print key with value